# DELETE method subrequests work in Sandbox but not Production

Tags: rest-api, webservices

User account making batch REST API requests from external application: DELETE method subrequests work in Sandbox but not Production

Issue: When an external application sends a request to the REST API Batch resource on Production, DELETE methods return 401 unauthorized. The user is a System Admin. When Sandbox user does a send, DELETEs are successful in the batch request.

The odd thing is that we are only having issues with DELETE method, not with GET, PATCH, etc methods. The token can't be invalid because GET & PATCH wouldn't work if it was.

Troubleshooting steps we’ve performed:

- Verified user account is system administrator. Profile and
  permissions are matching between Sandbox and Production.
- Verified session ID or OAuth token used has not expired nor is
  invalid.
- Verified correct protocol (using HTTPS not HTTP).

Comment: Are they hitting the correct endpoint or did they forget to change it from sandbox to production?

Comment: They confirmed they are hitting the correct endpoint. Further troubleshooting was going into workbench as the prod user and trying a delete against a test record; delete was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Going to answer my own question in case anyone else encounters the same issue. The answer is: The issue self-resolved. We confirmed it wasn't an issue in Salesforce and re-deploying didn't work. We just came in this morning and batch delete requests started working.